# Construct cv::Mat via C++ 1D array

Tags: c++, opencv

I took over a program, which use 1d array to construct cv::Mat. I'm confuse about it, and I make a demo:

```cpp
int main()
{
    short data[] = {
        11, 12, 13, 14,
        21, 22, 23, 24,
        31, 32, 33, 34,
        43, 42, 43, 44
    };

    cv::Mat m{ 4, 4, CV_8U, data};

    cv::imwrite("test.png", m);

    return 0;
}
```

I expect the output is

```cpp
11 12 13 14
21 22 23 24
31 32 33 34
43 42 43 44
```

But I open the img in MATLAB:

```cpp
11  0   12  0
13  0   14  0
21  0   22  0
23  0   24  0
```

Comment: `short` is at least 16 bits. Perhaps you meant to use `uchar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **3rd parameter** in the constructor you used for cv::Mat (`CV_8U`) specifies the **format** of the data buffer.

Your data is an array of `short`, i.e. each entry is 2 bytes. When you use values small values like you did, it means one of the bytes for each short will be 0.

When you use this buffer to initialized a `cv::Mat` of type `CV_8U` you tell opencv to treat the buffer as containing unsigned chars (1 byte elements). So each `short` is interpreted as 2 `unsigned char` bytes.

**This is why you get the zeroes in the output**.

Eaither change the type of the data buffer to `unsigned char []`, or change the `cv::Mat` data type to e.g. `CV_16S`. The 2 should usually match.

**You can do it e.g. like this:**

```
unsigned char data[] = {
    11, 12, 13, 14,
    21, 22, 23, 24,
    31, 32, 33, 34,
    43, 42, 43, 44
};

cv::Mat m{ 4, 4, CV_8U, data };
```

You can see the list of opencv data types here (in the *Data types* section):

https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/d1b/group__core__hal__interface.html

Comment: Thx friend, there is another problem. I found the previous programmer used `cv::Mat vidIn{ height, width, CV_8UC2, (unsigned char*)pBufShow };` , how did it worked on ch2?

Comment: Using `CV_8UC2` means each `cv::Mat` entry holds 2 channels of `unsigned char`, which (together) have the same `sizeof` as a `short`. The result will be that the first channel will hold the values you expect, and the second channel will hold zeroes (because of a reason similar to what I wrote in my answer).

Comment: BTW - when I wrote that the types of the data buffer and the cv::Mat should usually match, I meant as a rule of thumb. Of course you can do whaever you like as long as you understand the meaning. E.g. you can use `CV_8UC4` for cv::Mat and `uint32` for the data buffer. If the `uint32` values actually represent 4 byte channels it will work OK.